# Conditional statement to skip data query

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, microsoft-excel-365

I have a workbook that uses data sources from web (XML query) to pull some info in.  The server will return an error if I send a "0" or "blank" for one value, so I am trying to find a way to wrap one of my queries in a conditional `if statement` so that the query will only run if there is a positive value in a specific cell (that cell is named `SecondSize` if this is helpful).  I went to PowerEditor and then to Advanced Editor and have the info below but was unsure where (and how) to place an IF statement here.

```
let
    apiAddress = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiUrl2"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiAddress)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    Value = #"Converted to Table"{6}[Value],
    ac_monthly = Value[ac_monthly],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(ac_monthly, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Ignore)
in
    #"Converted to Table1"
```

In a truly ideal world, I would not only skip the query when the value is 0 or blank but I would also overwrite the 12 values in table1 with a "0"...but if that is too much I can do a conditional on another cell to manage that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear at the moment, but assuming that a successful API call returns 12 rows in a table, and that if SecondSize is not greater than 0, you want to return a 12-row table that has a zero on each row, then try this:

```
let
    apiAddress = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiUrl2"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    secondSize = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SecondSize"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],

    getResultAndProcess = (apiAddress) =>
        let
            Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiAddress)),
            asTable = Record.ToTable(Source),
            Value = asTable{6}[Value],
            ac_monthly = Value[ac_monthly],
            result = Table.FromList(ac_monthly, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Ignore)
        in
            result,

    result = 
        if secondSize > 0 
        then getResultAndProcess(apiAddress) 
        else Table.FromList(List.Repeat({0}, 12), Splitter.SplitByNothing())
in
    result
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much.  I can make complete sense out of the logic you applied...I just couldn't figure out where/how to make that happen.  This is working great.  Thanks @FlexYourData